# Script to check if python package is installed or not?

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following script:

```
import sys

try:
   k = sys.argv[1]
   import k
except ImportError, e:
   print "Package not found!!!"
```

When i run it in Command line > **Example.py requests**

I get msg "Package Not Found!!" even though request module is installed..

I know i am missing somewhere in 
**import k** line 
where in sys.argv[1] is taken as String & while using import {String} it would always give "Package Not Found!!"

Any help on what i am doing wrong in tiny little snippet might help.

Thanks in advance!! :)